# Error while superimposing 2 images in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, gaussian

I am running the below code to superimpose two images

```
A = 'gaussians.png';
B = 'gaussiansContour.png';

imAlphaData = repmat(0:1/size(B,2):1-1/size(B,2),size(B,1),1);

hf = figure('units','normalized','position',[.2 .2 .6 .6]);
ax1 = subplot(2,3,1);
ibg = image(A);
axis off;
title('Background');
ax2 = subplot(2,3,4);
iim = image(B);
axis off;
title('Image without transparency yet');

ax3 = subplot(2,3,[2:3, 5:6]);
ibg2 = image(B);
axis off;
hold on;
%   Overlay the image, and set the transparency previously calculated
iim2 = image(A,'XData',[30 50],'YData',[10 30]);
set(iim2,'AlphaData',imAlphaData);
title(sprintf('Using transparency while overlaying images:\nresult is multiple image objects.'));
```

But I am running into an error:

```
Error using image
Numeric or logical matrix required for image CData

Error in superimpose (line 8)
ibg = image(A);
```

Can anybody tell me what to change so that my code runs properly?

Comment: Which call to `image` is it exactly and what are the dimensions of its inputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`image` takes a matrix of pixel data, not a string.  Use `imread`

```
image(imread('gaussians.png'))
```

Comment: I did the same, but my matlab crashes and pc restarts when I run the program.

Comment: Running this MATLAB statement is very benign.  You've got a serious problem with your operating system / hardware if running the above code causes your PC to restart and MATLAB to crash.

Comment: @rayryeng that's for sure!  Did the CPU's heatsink fall off?  :)

Comment: @chappjc - hahahaha. I know right!?  I honestly cannot see how displaying a figure with an image in it would cause the PC to restart.  My guess is a RAM module is defective.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
A = imread('gaussians.png');
B = imread('gaussiansContour.png');
```

Instead of your:

```
A = 'gaussians.png';
B = 'gaussiansContour.png';
```